# Why am I getting this message in hackerrank "~ no response on stdout ~"? I don't know what I am missing>

Tags: c

Why am I getting this message in hackerrank "~ no response on stdout ~"? I don't know what I am missing?
I am bit frustrated right now because I have no clue about what to do.
So I was left with only choice to post this query on Stackoverflow.

Here is [the link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup)

Here is my complete code:

```
char* readline();
// Complete the countingValleys function below.
int countingValleys(int n, char* s) 
{
  int dwnhl = 0, level = 0;
  bool frmsurface = true;
  int k = strlen(s);
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) 
  {
    if (level == 0) 
    {
      frmsurface = true;
    }

    if (s[i] == 'D') 
    {
      level--;
      if ((level < 0) && (frmsurface == true)) 
      {
        dwnhl++;
        frmsurface = false;
        //printf("went downhill %d ",i);
      }
    } 
    else if (s[i] == 'U') 
    { //printf("went uphill %d ",i);
      level++;
    }
    // printf("\nhello - %c",s[i]);
  }

  printf("\nNumber of downhill = %d \n", dwnhl);
  return (dwnhl);
}

int main() 
{
  FILE* fptr = fopen(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"), "w");

  char* n_endptr;
  char* n_str = readline();
  int n = strtol(n_str, &n_endptr, 10);

  if (n_endptr == n_str || *n_endptr != '\0') 
  {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  char* s = readline();

  int result = countingValleys(n, s);

  printf("%d\n", result);

  return 0;
}

char* readline() 
{
  size_t alloc_length = 1024;
  size_t data_length = 0;
  char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

  while (true) 
  {
    char* cursor = data + data_length;
    char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

    if (!line) 
    {
      break;
    }

    data_length += strlen(cursor);

    if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n') 
    {
      break;
    }

    size_t new_length = alloc_length << 1;
    data = realloc(data, new_length);

    if (!data) 
    {
      break;
    }

    alloc_length = new_length;
  }

  if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') 
  {
    data[data_length - 1] = '\0';
  }

  data = realloc(data, data_length);

  return data;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? And where is the line when crash ? If doesn't crash, from where you get the message ?

Comment: Possibly unrelated to your problem, you have a fatal flaw in the `readline` function where you could use negative indexes in the string array. And a couple of fatal flaws where you don't check what `readline` return.

Comment: Does the question (I can't read the link) really ask for this output from `printf("\nNumber of downhill = %d \n", dwnhl);`? That seems unusual. Don't forget there is a robot checking the output which must exactly match what the question states the output shall be.

Comment: @WeatherVane notice that OP only wrote the code in the `countingValleys` function. All other code is given by hackerrank

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, if the robot is execting a single line of output then your message starts with an empty line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is the way you handle `frmsurface`

The first time you enter the loop `frmsurface` is set to true. If the events are `UUDD`, your code will still count a "valley" because you don't clear `frmsurface` when you go up.

Instead of

```
       if(level==0)               
       {                        
         frmsurface=true;     
       }
```

you could try:

```
       frmsurface = (level == 0);
```

but I don't really understand why you want the boolean. Just test for `level == 0` instead. Something like:

```
       if(s[i]=='D')  
       {
           if(level==0)
           {
               dwnhl++;
           }
           level--;
       }
       else if (s[i]=='U') 
       {
               level++;
       }
```

Also I wonder if this line:

```
printf("\nNumber of downhill = %d \n", dwnhl);
```

must be removed.

Notice that

```
   int k=strlen(s);
   for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
```

could probably just be

```
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                 ^
```

as `n` is passed to the function

Comment: Problem solved. I don't know what was the problem really. But I reset the code and typed again, and it worked. Maybe I was missing something. BTW thanks all for your responses.